# What does Ctrl + Up do in Geany?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, geany, ctrl

In Geany, some of my .txt files navigate to the previous section when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>. In my `.md` files, they do not.

It's as if the behaviour of this shortcut is somehow controlled by my syntax for headings or my indention.

Alas, I cannot find anything about it in Geany's documentation. What does the shortcut do?